# Typedef equivalence in function arguments

Tags: c++, templates, gcc, typedef

The question is kind of hard to ask without an example so here it is:

```
#include <vector>

struct O
{
};

struct C
{
  template <typename T>
  void function1(void (C::*callback)(const O*));

  template <typename T>
  void function2(void (C::*callback)(const typename T::value_type));

  void print(const O*);
};


int main()
{
  C c;

  c.function1< std::vector<O*> >(&C::print); // Success.
  c.function2< std::vector<O*> >(&C::print); // Fail.
}
```

The error that I am given is:

> `error: no matching function for call to ‘C::function2(void (C::*)(const O*))’`.

Basically, the only difference between calls is that in `function2`, I'm more generic since I use the typedef `std::vector<O*>::value_type` which should resolve to `O*`, hence similar to `function1`.

I'm using G++ 4.2.1 (I know it's old), but Comeau confirms I'm wrong.

**Why does the compilation fail?**

Comment: Oh, I'm starting to think that `const typename T::value_type` doesn't resolve to `const O*` but to `O* const`. How can I achieve what I want?

Comment: Exactly. Use traits to add constness.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is that `const typename T::value_type` is basically `typename T::value_type const` which resolves to `O* const` which is obviously not the same as `const O*` (which would be `O const *`, when writing the ptr declaration behind the type (more useful to figure out this behaviour)).

As for archiving what you want, that entirly depends on what you want. If you want you can use `boost type_traits` or `tr1 type_traits` to strip the pointer, add const and make it a pointer again like this:

```
template <typename T>
void function2(void (C::*callback)(typename boost::add_pointer<typename boost::add_const<typename boost::remove_pointer<typename T::value_type>::type>::type>::type));
```

Using `tr1` instead of `boost` should basically be a matter of replacing `boost::` with `std::tr1::`.

However I wouldn't exactly call this a useful generalization, so you might want to overthink if you really want to go that way. Personally I would either use something like `boost function` or free functions as callbacks, the former allowing for much greater flexibility in what can be used as callbacks (free functions, functors, member functions), while the later at least makes it easy to create a second function which will appropriately convert the arguments (that is if you want to use a function which gets `const O*` as parameter, you can create one which takes `O*` and calls the first one with that parameter and use that one as callback).

Comment: A member function pointer whose target is the same as the caller only needs `&C::print`. A `boost::function` needs `boost::bind(&C::print, this)`. So it's "easier". Moreover, it wouldn't solve anything since the callback still needs an argument whose type is depending on the template typename.